# apoc.cypher.mapParallel2 in Neo4j is not giving expected results

Tags: neo4j, parallel-processing, cypher

I have the following query

```
MATCH (e) WHERE SIZE((e:Customer)<-[:Transaction]-()) <> 0
AND SIZE(()<-[:Transaction]-(e)) <> 0
MATCH path = (e)-[:Transaction*..10]-(e) return path
```

I am getting the expected results with the above query.

I am trying to parallelize this query with the following query

```
MATCH (e:Customer) WHERE SIZE((e)<-[:Transaction]-()) <> 0 AND SIZE(()<-[:Transaction]-(e)) <> 0 WITH 
collect(e.ID) AS users CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel2("match (e:Customer)-[:Transaction*..10]->(e) 
where e.ID=_ return e.ID as ll",{},users,10) yield value return value.ll
```

this query doesn't return anything. Kindly, please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this query, which is also more efficient, work for you?

```
MATCH (e:Customer) 
WHERE (e)<-[:Transaction]-() AND ()<-[:Transaction]-(e)
WITH collect(e) AS users
CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel2(
  "match (_)-[:Transaction*..10]->(_) return _.ID as ll",
  {},users,10) YIELD value
RETURN value.ll
```

Comment: No, still not producing any results.